# Insert into dest and update source

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, is it possible to insert data from a source table into a dest table and update the source table with @@identity from the dest table at the same time?

Example

Table Source:

```
Id - UniqueId
Name - varchar(10) 
RealId [null] - int
```

Table Dest

```
Id - [id] INT identity
Name - varchar(10)
```

I want to transfer rows from Source into Dest, and update the `RealId` to the @@identity value from the Dest table

I can modify Source in any way I like, the Dest table may not be altered.

What are my best options here?

Also note, the "Name" column may contain duplicates so I can't really join on that.

(The real tables are much more complex, but this should give and idea of what I want)

Comment: First comment: use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@Identity` - it's safer and more true to what you're really looking for. Second: if you want to insert into dest and then update source, you need to have **some** field that is the same in both - if `name` can't do it, then you need something else, e.g. `SourceId` on the `Dest` table or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this question. [Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id) .
You can use output from merge to get a table variable with a link between id's in source and target. Then you can use that table to update your source table.