# SQL - Clone a record and its descendants

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to be able to clone a record and its descendants in the same table. An example of my table would be the following:

Table1

```
id | parentid | name
---------------------
 1 |    0     |  'Food'
 2 |    1     |  'Taste'
 3 |    1     |  'Price'
 4 |    2     |  'Taste Requirements'
```

The "id" column is the primary key and auto-increments. The 'Food' record (i.e. where id = 1) has two records underneath it called 'Taste' and 'Price'. The 'Taste' record has a record underneath it called 'Taste Requirements'. I would like to be able to clone the 'Food' record so that Table1 would look like the following:

Table1

```
id | parentid | name
---------------------
 1 |    0     |  'Food'
 2 |    1     |  'Taste'
 3 |    1     |  'Price'
 4 |    2     |  'Taste Requirements'
 5 |    0     |  'Cookies'
 6 |    5     |  'Taste'
 7 |    5     |  'Price'
 8 |    6     |  'Taste Requirements'
```

(where 'Cookies' is the name of the new category that I want to create). I am able to select all the descendants of 'Food' using:

```
with Table1_CTE( id, parentid, name )
as
(
  select t.id, t.parentid, t.name from Table1 t
    where t.id = 1
  union all
  select t.id, t.parentid,t. name from Table1 t
    inner join Table1_CTE as tc
      on t.parentid = tc.id
)
select id, parentid, name from Table1_CTE
```

and I am able to clone just the 'Food' record (i.e. where id = 1) using:

```
insert into Table1 ( parentid, name )
  select ( parentid, 'Cookies' ) 
  from Table1 where id = 1
```

but I am having problems trying to combine the two queries to clone the descendants of 'Food'. Also, I am trying to avoid using stored procedures, triggers, curosrs, etc. Is what I am trying to do possible? I have seen some examples on the web but have been unable to apply them to my requirements.

Comment: As `id` is an `identity` column I think your only options are to do as many `insert` operations as there are levels in the hierarchy and capture the newly inserted `id`s with the `output` clause or to block any concurrent insert attempts, calculate the `id` values yourself then insert them in one operation with `identity_insert` on.

Comment: I wonder if you could use an insert trigger?

Comment: If the names are not guaranteed to be unique, you may end up doing as may inserts as there are *rows* in the hierarchy, unless you use MERGE, which allows you to insert entire levels in sets while remembering the linkings between the source and the target. You can read more about the technique [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Martin suggested, you need to enable `IDENTITY_INSERT` so that you can push your own identity values. You may also need to acquire a table lock to ensure that Max( Id ) returns the correct value.

```
If object_id('tempdb..#TestData') is not null
    Drop Table #TestData
GO
Create Table #TestData
    (
    Id int not null identity(1,1) Primary Key
    , ParentId int not null
    , Name varchar(50) not null
    )
GO
Set Identity_Insert #TestData On
GO  
Insert #TestData( Id, ParentId, Name )
Values( 1,0,'Food' )
    , ( 2,1,'Taste' )
    , ( 3,1,'Price' )
    , ( 4,2,'Taste Requirement' );


With Data As
    (
    Select Cast(MaxId.Id + 1 As int) As Id
        , T.ParentId
        , 'Copy Of ' + T.name As Name
        , T.Id As OldId
        , 0 As OldParentId
    From #TestData As T
        Cross Join( Select Max( id ) As Id From #TestData ) As MaxId
    Where T.Name = 'Food'
    Union All
    Select Cast(Parent.id + Row_Number() Over( Order By Child.Id ) + 1 As int)
        , Parent.Id
        , 'Copy of ' + Child.Name
        , Child.Id
        , Child.ParentId
    From Data As Parent
        Join #TestData As Child
            On Child.ParentId = Parent.OldId
    )
Insert #TestData( Id, ParentId, Name )
Select Id, ParentId, Name
From Data
GO
Set Identity_Insert #TestData Off
GO
```

Results

```
id | parentid | name
-- | -------- | -----------------
1  | 0        | Food
2  | 1        | Taste
3  | 1        | Price
4  | 2        | Taste Requirement
5  | 0        | Copy Of Food
7  | 5        | Copy of Taste
8  | 5        | Copy of Price
9  | 7        | Copy of Taste Requirement
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CTE picks a root record and all it's descendents (it didn't seem to when I reproduced using your data above), then you can clone all selected records and insert like this:

```
with Table1_CTE( id, parentid, name )
as
(
  select t.id, t.parentid, t.name from Table1 t
    where c.icategoryid = 1
  union all
  select t.id, t.parentid,t. name from Table1
    inner join Table1_CTE as tc
      on t.parentid = tc.id
)
insert into  dbo.testinsertheirarchy  ( parentid, name )  
select  parentid, name from Table1_CTE
```