# How to fill table variable with correct IDENTITY values?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Well, I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Temp(
        TEMP_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ... )

CREATE TABLE TEMP1(
    TEMP1_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    TEMP_ID int, ... )
```

they are linked with TEMP_ID foreign key. 
In a stored procedure I need to create tons of 
Temp and Temp1 rows and update them, so I created a table variable (@TEMP) and I am dealing with it and finally make one big INSERT into Temp. My question is: how can I fill @Temp with correct TEMP_ID's without insert safely from multiple sessions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Scope_Identity() to find out last inserted row. You can use Output clause to find all newly inserted (or updated) rows.

```
create table #t1
(
    id int primary key identity,
    val int
)


Insert into #t1 (val) 
    output inserted.id, inserted.val
    values (10), (20), (30)
```

Comment: in this case after INSERT into Temp from @Temp I can retrieve a list of TEMP_ID's, but how can I fix TEMP_ID's of Temp1 then?

Comment: @QuéPadre have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074999/t-sql-insert-original-value-in-output-clause