# How to copy rows with SQL and get new and old IDs as result?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I need to copy certain rows. I can get IDs of new rows like this:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (ID int)
INSERT T (name, address)
OUTPUT INSERTED.TID INTO @ids
    SELECT name, address
    FROM T
```

But what I would like to have is something like this:

```
DECLARE @IDs TABLE (oldID int, newID int)
INSERT T (name, address)
OUTPUT T.ID, INSERTED.TID INTO @ids
    SELECT name, address
    FROM T
```

Can this be done with SQL Server?

P.S. I'm not doing this programmaticaly, because it has to be done by a stored procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy tables avoiding cursors in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174355/how-to-copy-tables-avoiding-cursors-in-sql)

Comment: Basically, explore [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id "Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id")'s *Linked* section: a lot of questions link to it, and many are similar to yours.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  There would be no "old" `ID` for an inserted row.  Are you talking about updates?

Comment: @Shark: I'm not taking about UPDATEs. What I was trying to do is duplicate certain rows in a table and as a result get pairs of IDs that show which old/existing row was duplicated into which new row.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With helpful links from [Andriy M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297408/andriy-m)'s link to '[How to copy tables avoiding cursors in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174355/how-to-copy-tables-avoiding-cursors-in-sql)', I managed to come up with this very elegant solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (oID int, nID int);

MERGE T s
USING (
        SELECT TID, name, address
        FROM T [s]
      ) d on 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (name, address)
    VALUES (name, address)
OUTPUT d.TID as oID, Inserted.TID as nID
INTO @t;
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't scored higher, it's very handy, thanks. Would be easier to read with more descriptive var names. :) `T s` could be `MyTable tblTo`, `T [s]` just `MyTable`, and `d` could be `tblFrom`.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find anywhere. It's sad SQL Server can't accept SELECT on INSERT VALUES.