# TSQL Bulk insert data while returning created id's to original table

Tags: t-sql, insert, bulk

I have two tables. One called @tempImportedData, another called @tempEngine.
I have data in @tempImportedData I would like to put this data into @tempEngine, once inserted into @tempEngine an id gets created. I would like that id to be placed back into @tempImportedData in the corresponding row. I believe this this the purpose of OUTPUT statement. I almost have a working copy please see below.

```
Declare @tempEngine as table(
     id int identity(4,1) not null
    ,c1 int
    ,c2 int
);
Declare @tempImportedData as table(
     c1 int
    ,c2 int
    ,engine_id int
);
insert into @tempImportedData  (c1, c2)
    select 1,1
    union all select 1,2
    union all select 1,3
    union all select 1,4
    union all select 2,1
    union all select 2,2
    union all select 2,3
    union all select 2,4
;
INSERT INTO @tempEngine ( c1, c2 ) 
    --OUTPUT INSERTED.c1, INSERTED.c2, INSERTED.id  INTO @tempImportedData (c1, c2, engine_id) --dups with full data
    --OUTPUT INSERTED.id  INTO @tempImportedData (engine_id) -- new rows with wanted data, but nulls for rest
    SELECT 
         c1
        ,c2
    FROM 
        @tempImportedData
;       
select * from @tempEngine ;
select * from @tempImportedData ;
```

I've commented out two lines starting with OUTPUT.

The problem with the first is that it inserts all of the correct data into @tempImportedData, so the end result is that 16 rows exist, the first 8 are the same with a null value for engine_id while the third column is null; the remaining 8 have all three columns populated. The end result should have 8 rows not 16.

The second OUTPUT statement has the same problem as the first - 16 rows instead of 8. However the new 8 rows contain null, null, engine_id

So how can I alter this TSQL to get @tempImportedData.engine_id updated without inserting new rows?

Answer (score 2):

You need another table variable (`@temp`) to capture the output from the insert and then run a update statement using the `@temp` against `@tempImportedData` joining on `c1` and `c2`. This requires that the combination of `c1` and `c2` is unique in `@tempImportedData`.

```
Declare @temp as table(
     id int
    ,c1 int
    ,c2 int
);

INSERT INTO @tempEngine ( c1, c2 ) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id, INSERTED.c1, INSERTED.c2 INTO @temp
    SELECT 
         c1
        ,c2
    FROM 
        @tempImportedData
;       

UPDATE T1
  SET engine_id = T2.id
FROM @tempImportedData as T1
  INNER JOIN @temp as T2
    on T1.c1 = T2.c1 and
       T1.c2 = T2.c2
;
```

Comment: This is sort of what I was afraid of, I do not have a unique set of values in my actual data, works fine in this example though. -Thanks!

Comment: @zdox - If you add a identity column to `@tempImportedData` you can use that as a unique key to reference back. To use `output` with insert you need to move the identity column to your target table to get a match but if you have SQL Server 2008 you can use merge to get the job done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id

Answer (score 0):

@tempImportedData still has the old data still in it.  The first OUTPUT statement seems to be inserting the right data in the new rows, but the old rows are still there. If you run a DELETE on @tempImportedData taking away all rows where engine_id is null at the end of your script, you should be left the correct eight rows.