# Duplicate records with identity column

Tags: t-sql

Consider the following design:

```
Company TABLE (
    CompanyId int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyName nvarchar(max))
Product TABLE (
    ProductId int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    CompanyId int NOT NULL,
    ProductName nvarchar(max))
ProductPart TABLE (
    ProductPartId int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductId int NOT NULL,
    ProductPartName)
```

I need to duplicate a company (with `CompanyId == @companyId`) data so it will contain exactly the same data.

The first step is obvious:

```
INSERT INTO Company(CompanyName)
SELECT @newCompanyName
FROM Company
WHERE CompanyId = @companyId

DECLARE @newCompanyId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Without `ProductPart` table it would be trivial to copy `Product` data as well:

```
INSERT INTO Product (ProductName)
SELECT ProductName
FROM Product
WHERE CompanyId = @companyId
```

But in order to duplicate `ProductPart` data properly I need to have product mapping data between old and new companies.

I tried to use `OUTPUT` clause but unfortunately it doesn't support my scenario:

```
DECLARE @productRemap TABLE (OldProductId int NOT NULL, NewProductId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO Product (ProductName)
    OUTPUT ProductId, inserted.ProductId
        INTO @productRemap
SELECT ProductName
FROM Product
WHERE CompanyId = @companyId
-- Invalid column name 'ProductId'.
```

Is there any way to copy the data properly without involving cursors?

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2008 you could use `merge` instead. Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mikael I found that I can actually use `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`:

```
DECLARE @productRemap
    TABLE (OldProductId int NOT NULL, NewProductId int NOT NULL)

-- Duplicate products
MERGE INTO Product AS t
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM Product
    WHERE CompanyId = @companyId) AS s
ON (0 = 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ProductName, CompanyId)
    VALUES (ProductName, @newCompanyId)
    OUTPUT s.ProductId, inserted.ProductId
        INTO @productRemap;
```

Then I can insert into `ProductPart` using mapping from `@productRemap`:

```
MERGE INTO ProductPart AS t
USING (
    SELECT * FROM ProductPart
        INNER JOIN @productRemap ON ProductId = OldProductId) AS s
ON (0 = 1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ProductId, ProductPartName)
    VALUES (NewProductId, ProductPartName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're looking to do this strictly with TSQL, however, form experience I have found it easiest to add an `OldProductId` field to the `Product` table and map Product Parts from that:

```
INSERT INTO Product (ProductName, OldProductId)
SELECT ProductName, ProductId
FROM Product
WHERE CompanyId = @companyId
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add any additional columns to `Product` table