# How to clone a set of related records in SQL Server, thinking about T-SQL in Store Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I need to clone a record from a master table and all related child tables, there are about 10.

Currently I believe the approach would be to write all the SELECT and INSERT T-SQL statements in a Stored Procedure. Obviously this will take a little time as there are 10 tables, and some of the tables have quite a few columns. Is there another approach which would be quicker to implement ie some form of "cascade copy".

Thanks.

EDIT:

It seems I cannot do:

```
insert into Table1
select *
from Table1 
where Id = 1082
```

I get:

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Table1' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

Comment: select * into <newtable> from <basetable>

Comment: ok, yes :). Also I am now researching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727850/cascade-copy-of-rows-in-sql

Comment: Actually I am inserting another record into the same <basetable>. But my question is really whether I need to then explicitly write "insert" statements to do all the cloning for all of the child records from the child tables. I appreciate I can use Select * in the Insert statements, but I still need to write an Insert statement for each child table, or am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Your current belief would be the correct method. Don't try and cut corners, it's only a bit of typing ;) Remember that SSMS can generate certain scripts for you (right-click, script table as, insert to) which might help!

Comment: @gvee, Appreciate the comment :) Just checking my belief.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use SET IDENTITY_INSERT X ON & just keep this in mind *
It is must to mention the column list after the table name

try your insert statement like this (mention column name) --

```
insert into Table1 (id,a,b,b)
select id,a,b,c
from Table1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually found that "SET IDENTITY_INSERT X OFF" is needed in my case where I would need to create a fresh Id which is the Identity column