# Copying multiple row and it's related rows in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Does anyone know a simple way of copying multiple table rows and it's related items?

In my simplified example I have two tables, one with a table for companies and one for their employees and I'd like to be able to clone entire companies with all their employees in a simple way.

```
[Companies]

- ID (Auto-increment)
- Name

[Employees]

- ID
- CompanyID (Foreign Key)
- Name
```

I've been playing around with the `OUTPUT`-clause but just managed to return the inserted IDs without a reference to the original row.

**I just can't figure out how to link a inserted row to the original one?**

If the insert-statement returned a table like this:

```
@mappingTable

-InsertedCompanyID
-OriginalCompanyID
```

I could run a statement like this to copy all employees:

```
INSERT INTO Employees (CompanyID, Name)
SELECT m.InsertedCompanyID, x.Name FROM @mappingTable m 
INNER JOIN Employees x (x.CompanyID = m.OriginalCompanyID)
```

Or am I on the wrong path? Is there's a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use the output clause with `merge`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you! Make it an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the output clause of the `merge` statment to map between the old ID and the new auto incremented ID.

Have a look at this question: [Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)