# Inserting batch of rows into two tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to insert multiple rows into `table1` and at the same time insert a row into `table2` with a `pkID` from `table1` and a value that comes from a SP parameter.

I created a stored procedure that performs a batch insert with a table valued parameter which contains the rows to be inserted into `table1`. But I have a problem with inserting the row into `table2` with the corresponding Id (identity) from `table1`, along with parameter value that I have passed.

Is there anyone who implemented this, or what is the good solution for this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[oSP_TV_Insert]
  @uID int
  ,@IsActive int
  ,@Type int -- i need to insert this in table 2
  ,@dTableGroup table1  READONLY -- this one is a table valued
AS

DECLARE @SQL varchar(2000)
DECLARE @table1Id int
 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.table1  
        (uID
        ,Name
        ,Contact
        ,Address
        ,City
        ,State
        ,Zip
        ,Phone
        ,Active)  
    SELECT 
        @uID  
        ,Name
        ,Contact
        ,Address
        ,City
        ,State
        ,Zip
        ,Phone
        ,Active
        ,@G_Active   
    FROM @dTableGroup
--the above query will perform batch insert using the records from dTableGroup which is table valued

SET @table1ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- this below will perform inserting records to table2 with every Id inserted in table1.

Insert into table2(@table1ID , @type)
```

Comment: Can you post the code and what you think is not working properly? If you have a problem with obtaining identity value of inserted record, `INSERT` has `OUTPUT` clause that will give you that value.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly and you are on 2008 see [Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to temporarily store the inserted identity values and then create a second INSERT statement - using the OUTPUT clause.

Something like:

```
-- declare table variable to hold the ID's that are being inserted
DECLARE @InsertedIDs TABLE (ID INT)

-- insert values into table1 - output the inserted ID's into @InsertedIDs
INSERT INTO dbo.table1(ID, Name, Contact, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Active)  
     OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @InsertedIDs
     SELECT 
         @ID, Name, Contact, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Active, @G_Active   
    FROM @dTableGroup
```

and then you can have your second INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table2(Table1ID, Type)
    SELECT ID, @type FROM @InsertedIDs
```

See the [MSDN docs on the OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) for more details on what you can do with the OUTPUT clause - one of the most underused and most "unknown" features of SQL Server these days!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need all inserted identity values, look at the output clause of the insert statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: i think the scope_identity got here is the last one?what about the first one?

Comment: What is the name of your identity column? It doesn't look like it is ID, since you're providing a value in the stored procedure insert statement.