# Complex TSQL Merge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, merge, upsert

I have '*inherited*' a brilliant piece of TSQL code that does this:

- Loops row-by-row over a cursor.
- The cursor contains data that need to be merged (Upserted) in Table A
- For each row loop in the cursor a stored proc is called. The proc:

  - If a corresponding row exists in Table A then it is updated
  - If such a row does not exist then:

    - Inserts a single row in in a different Table B.
    - Fetches the newly generated ID (say its called IDB)
    - Inserts a single row in Table A. Table A insertions *need* an IDB (the field is not null, it is supposed to have values ONLY from table B, but no FK constraint is in place)

Obviously this sucks (performance & elegance reasons)!!

**Question**
At first this looks like a standard case of MERGE usage. I tried doing:

```
MERGE [dbo].[TableA] AS Target
USING <cursor data set as a select statement> as Src on target.IDA = Src.IDA
WHEN MATCHED 
  //update
WHEN NOT MATCHED
//insert <------ Fails because obviously a new IDB is required
```

Also tried various approaches like a `nested select that sends IDB on the OUTPUT` but it fails because IDB is a PK.

Other kinds of merges also failed eg:

```
MERGE Table A with <cursor data set as a select statement>
...
MERGE Table A with Table B
WHEN NOT MATCHED
//insert on Table A
WHEN NOT MATCHED
// Update Table B
```

Does anyone have an idea on this? Essentially I think if we generalise the question would be:

`Can I insert and return the PK in one statement that can be nested in other statements`

Thanks in advance for any replies

George

Comment: You can merge into tableB and use the [technique here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5365629/73226) I think.

Comment: Thanks, saw that. Its actually a nice idea. Essentially the guy stores newly generated Ids in temp variables. Not the same as what I was looking for (to do the whole process in 1 Merge) but its still an interesting approach. Thanks Martin.

Comment: +1 for using the word 'upserted'...:)

Comment: What is IDB? Is it possible to change that IDB to a autoincrement, or default value of somesort? Also, can you essentially wrap the act of generating a new ID into a function and then be able to use that in your merge statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an autogenerated PK on TableB, you can use code similar to this.  Otherwise, just change the INSERT into TableA to grab the PK from TableB first.

```
DECLARE @OldData CHAR(10)
SET @OldData = 'Old'
DECLARE @NewData CHAR(10)
SET @NewData = 'New'

CREATE TABLE #TableA 
(
    IDA INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    IDB INT NOT NULL,
    DataA CHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #TableB 
(
    IDB INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    DataB CHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @IDsToUpsert TABLE
(
    ID INT
)

-- Add test values for existing rows 
INSERT INTO #TableB
OUTPUT INSERTED.IDB, @OldData
INTO #TableA
SELECT @OldData UNION ALL
SELECT @OldData UNION ALL
SELECT @OldData UNION ALL
SELECT @OldData 

-- Add test values for the rows to upsert
INSERT INTO @IDsToUpsert
SELECT 1 UNION -- exists
SELECT 3 UNION -- exists
SELECT 5 UNION -- does not exist
SELECT 7 UNION -- does not exist
SELECT 9       -- does not exist

-- Data Before
SELECT * From #TableA
SELECT * From #TableB

DECLARE rows_to_update CURSOR
    FOR SELECT ID FROM @IDsToUpsert

DECLARE @rowToUpdate INT
DECLARE @existingIDB INT

OPEN rows_to_update;

FETCH NEXT FROM rows_to_update 
INTO @rowToUpdate;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        IF NOT EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM #TableA WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
            WHERE IDA = @rowToUpdate            
        )
        BEGIN
            -- Insert into B, then insert new val into A
            INSERT INTO #TableB
            OUTPUT INSERTED.IDB, INSERTED.DataB 
            INTO #TableA
            SELECT @NewData
            -- Change code here if PK on TableB is not autogenerated
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Update
            UPDATE #TableA
            SET DataA = @NewData
            WHERE IDA = @rowToUpdate
        END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    FETCH NEXT FROM rows_to_update 
    INTO @rowToUpdate;
END

CLOSE rows_to_update;
DEALLOCATE rows_to_update;

SELECT * FROM #TableA
SELECT * FROM #TableB

DROP TABLE #TableA
DROP TABLE #TableB
```

Comment: I think its a very nice answer; this <100point poster thanks you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your general question - 'Can I insert and return the PK in one statement that can be nested in other statements' - yes, absolutely. But it depends on the logic behind the creation of your PK. In this case, it seems like to generate a PK, you need to insert into a different table and then grab the newly generated ID from there. This is not very efficient (IMHO) unless there is a very specific reason for doing so. Autoincrements, GUIDs, etc tend to work better as PKs. If you can simplify/change the logic behind this, and you can find a simpler way to accomplish that, so the PK 'CAN' be generated in one statment/function and thus can be used in other statements.