# Using OUTPUT with joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Why doesn't the following work?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Pending_Break 
  (Pending_Pod_ID, Break_Date_Time, Break_Length, Booked_Length)            
OUTPUT INSERTED.Pending_BH_ID -- This is the inserted identity
     , INSERTED.Pending_Pod_ID
     , INSERTED.Break_Name
     , INSERTED.Break_Date_Time
     , pb.PENDING_BH_ID  -- complains on this one
  INTO #InsertedPendingBreaks
 SELECT ippod.Pending_Pod_ID,  
        pb.Break_Date_Time
        pb.break_length,  
        0
   FROM PendingBreak pb
   JOIN InsertedPod ippod ON ...
```

Can I not use anything other than Inserted or Deleted in the OUTPUT clause?

Comment: Where did you hear of `updated`?

Comment: `INSERTED` and `DELETED` only, `UPDATED` doesn't exist in the [TSQL OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).  You've got identically named columns, which would require a column alias to tell them apart...

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are correct.  Question `UPDATED`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inserted` and `deleted` tables are available only in DML triggers.  I'm not sure if you just pulled a code snippet out of a trigger, but if that is a standalone batch then it won't work.

Also, there is no updated table.  An update is a delete and then an insert for this.  `deleted` contains the old data and `inserted` contains the new data on an UPDATE.

Comment: Not only in triggers. Also in the output clause. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Can I not use anything other than Inserted or Deleted in the OUTPUT
>   clause?

No you can't. At least not with an [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx). In SQL Server 2008 you can convert your [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) to a [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement instead and there you can use values from the source table in the output clause.

Have a look at this question how to do that in SQL Server 2008. [Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)