# Copy parent and child rows into same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a situation similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7955315/524861) where I want to copy parent rows and their child rows from and into the same table.

The suggested answer using `OUTPUT` and `MERGE` is clean but only considers just one record.

Is there a way to modify it to handle multiple parent rows?

**EDIT**

I tried to modify the SQL statement and came up with this:

```
DECLARE @fromId int, @toId int;
SET @fromId = 1;
SET @toId = 2;

DECLARE @mapping TABLE (old_id int, new_id int);

INSERT INTO parent_table (col1, col2, col3) 
SELECT @toId, col2, col3
FROM parent_table
WHERE col1 = @fromId;

MERGE child_table tgt
USING (
  SELECT t.parent_id, t.col2, t.col3
  FROM child_table t
  inner join parent_table p on p.id = t.parent_id
  WHERE p.col1 = @toId
) src
ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (parent_id, col2, col3) VALUES   (src.parent_id, src.col2, src.col3)
OUTPUT src.parent_id, INSERTED.parent_id INTO @mapping (old_id, new_id);
```

The first `INSERT` of the parent rows works. However, the second insert does insert any child rows. What am I missing?

Comment: Share some sample records. Hoping values with parent_id 2 are present in child table.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a UNION operator. We just have to focus on maintaining the column numbers and data types :

```
 select <required-column names, add null if value for a column not required> from parent_table 
    UNION
    select <required-column with null if value for that column not required> from child_table where id in(select id from parent_table);
```

For e.g. suppose destination has five columns, parent has three columns, child has two columns.
Then, depending on where parent ids should go, we could write :

```
insert into destination(col1,col2, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, null, col2, col3, null from parent_table where key in(<key values>)
UNION 
select col1, col2, null, null,null from child_table where key in(<key values>);
```

If all records are to be copied :

```
insert into destination(col1,col2, col3, col4, col5)
select col1, null, col2, col3, null from parent_table
UNION 
select col1, col2, null, null,null from child_table where key_column in(select key_column from parent_table);
```