# Simplest way to insert a related row for each row in a table and link them together?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the simplest way to insert a `Car` for each user in `Users` and set the  users `CarID` to the `ID` of the inserted `Car`?

```
[Users]

- ID
- Name
- CarID

[Cars]

- ID (Auto increment)
- Name
```

Sorry if this might be a duplicate question but I can't find any simple solutions. Everything I've found is using complicated cursors, pointers etc.

A simple and reusable syntax for this would save me hours while migrating data during system upgrades etc.

Comment: The 'simplest' way would be to not use a system generated value to associate users with cars but instead use something that exists in the real world outside of the database, verifiable in reality, familiar to users, etc perhaps licence plate number or VIN. (Your cars have names?! perhaps use those :)

Comment: You're right. But if it weren't I wouldn't ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or later you can use merge and output something like this.

Sample tables and data:

```
declare @Users table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(10) not null,
  CarID int null
);

declare @Cars table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(10) not null
);

insert into @Users(Name) values ('User1'),('User2'),('User3');
```

Add one care for each user and move the auto-generated CarID back to Users.

```
declare @ID table(CarID int, UserID int)

merge @Cars as C
using @Users as U
on 0 = 1
when not matched then
  insert (Name) values ('CarName')
output inserted.ID, U.ID into @ID;

update U
set CarID = I.CarID
from @Users as U
  inner join @ID as I
    on U.ID = I.UserID
```

Try it out on [SE Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61678/add-some-cars).

More info on the merge/output trick can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id).

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for :) Thanks! +1 for the nice example in SE Data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code you're using lets you call stored procedures?

```
create procedure dbo.CarUserInsert_sp
(
@p_UserID int,
@p_UserName varchar(100),
@p_CarID int,
@p_CarName  varchar(100)
)
as

if not exists ( select 1 from Cars where ID = @p_CarID )
  insert Cars values ( @p_CarID, @p_CarName )

if exists (select 1 from Users where ID = @p_UserID )
  update Users set Name = @p_UserName, CarID = @p_CarID where ID = @p_UserID
else 
  insert Users values ( @p_UserID, @p_UserName,  @p_CarID )

go
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
insert into cars (name)
select distinct(name) from users

update user 
set carId = (select ID from cars where cars.name=user.Name)
```

Comment: FYI, I honestly didn't understand very well what you need. It was just a guess

Comment: Yes but Cars doesn't have a userID?

Comment: again, not sure what you nedd. If the carId is autoincrement do you want to insert records in Cars with the same name as the user name? If yes, I updated my code to do that