# T-SQL: CTE with identity columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, identity-column

I'm building a tree (bill of materials style), and transforming some data. Consider the following table:

BillOfMaterials

- BomId
- ParentId

Now I'm using a CTE to fill it up:

```
with BOM as 
(
select @@identity as BomId, null as ParentId <some other fields> from MyTable
union all
select @@identity as BomId, 
       parent.BomId as ParentId,
       some other fields
from MyTable2
inner join BOM parent on blabla)

insert into MyTable3
select * from BOM
```

Problem is: the @@identity will only give me the identity of the last record inserted before the union.

What can I do to get the identity? I can modify Table3 but not Table1 or Table2

`row_number()` has undefined behavior for a recursive query, so I cannot use it here.

I know I can use a GUID, is that the only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't capture the generated identity in the CTE. You can however insert all rows to the target table with `null` as `ParentID` and then update `ParentID` in a separate update statement. To do that you can use `merge` and a technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id).

```
-- Helper table to map new id's from source
-- against newly created id's in target
declare @IDs table
( 
  TargetID int,
  SourceID int,
  SourceParentID int
)

-- Use merge to capture generated id's
merge BillOfMaterials as T
using SourceTable as S
on 1 = 0
when not matched then
insert (SomeColumn) values(SomeColumn)
output inserted.BomId, S.BomID, S.ParentID into @IDs;

-- Update the parent id with the new id
update T
set ParentID = I2.TargetID
from BillOfMaterials as T
  inner join @IDs as I1
    on T.BomID = I1.TargetID
  inner join @IDs as I2
    on I1.SourceParentID = I2.SourceID
```

Here is full working sample on [SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/67718)

Answer (score 2):

`@@identity` shows you actual identity value for your session.

You can't use `CTE` with `IDENTITY FUNCTION` but you can use temp table:

```
SELECT IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS  BomId, un.*
INTO #BOM
FROM <your union> as un
```

If you want to use CTE:

```
with BOM as 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <column> ) AS  BomId, un.*
  FROM <your union> as un
)
```

Comment: row_number() has undefined behavior for a recursive query.

Comment: Hmm I didin't know about that. That's strange. I cannot find better/other option. So probably you have to use NEWID().

Comment: Bas, in my team we have been using row_number() in CTE for a lot of time and various implementations. We have not found any problems. What exactly do you mean?