# Iterate sql data with cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So, I have an SQL table called "bom".

- ParentPartId
- ChildPartId

Imagine I have table full of data such as (unknown amount of sub-levels):

```
| PARENTPARTID  |  CHILDPARTID |
+---------------+--------------+
| NK-FS-DR-62DR | 2001020060   |
| 2001020060    | 2002014018   |
| 2002014018    | 120011       |
| NK-WH-DR-3MH  | 2001916023   |
```

Basically I want to select "NK-FS-DR-62DR" which would select all the child parts below it so it would look like

```
| PARENTPARTID  |  CHILDPARTID |
+---------------+--------------+
| NK-FS-DR-62DR | 2001020060   |
| 2001020060    | 2002014018   |
| 2002014018    | 120011       |
```

`boms` can go unknown amount of levels deep.

So, I'm looking for some form of cursor to literal all the sublevels.

I currently have a cursor but I can't think of a way to iterate the data.

Here is my current code (Only goes level 1 deep):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpBillOfMaterial
(
    ParentPartId VARCHAR(18),
    ChildPartId VARCHAR(18)
)

DECLARE @ParentPartId VARCHAR(18)

INSERT INTO #tmpBillOfMaterial ( ParentPartId, ChildPartId )
SELECT b.ParentPartId, b.ChildPartId
FROM jbds.BoM b
WHERE b.ParentPartId = 'NK-FS-DR-62DR'

DECLARE cursorStage1 CURSOR FOR  
SELECT b.ChildPartId
FROM jbds.BoM b
WHERE b.ParentPartId = 'NK-FS-DR-62DR'

OPEN cursorStage1  
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorStage1 INTO @ParentPartId  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    INSERT INTO #tmpBillOfMaterial ( ParentPartId, ChildPartId )
    SELECT b.ParentPartId, b.ChildPartId
    FROM jbds.BoM b
    WHERE b.ParentPartId = @ParentPartId

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorStage1 INTO @ParentPartId  
END  

CLOSE cursorStage1  
DEALLOCATE cursorStage1 


SELECT *
FROM #tmpBillOfMaterial

DROP TABLE #tmpBillOfMaterial
```

I've tried adding cursor within cursor but can only get 2 levels deep instead of it iterating all the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: CTE with identity columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278737/t-sql-cte-with-identity-columns)

Comment: I think you're looking for is a Oracle's "connect by" equivalent in SQL Server. Is that it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest is to use a recursive CTE:

```
;with x as (
select parentpartid, childpartid
from bom
where parentpartid = 'NK-FS-DR-62DR'
union all
select bom.parentpartid, bom.childpartid
from bom
inner join x on bom.parentpartid = x.childpartid
)
select * from x
```

Comment: In general, it's best to avoid cursors.  Recursive solutions tend to be so much cleaner, too...