# SQL Server 2005 Merging without the MERGE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2005, syntax

I have managed to produce a result set into a temp table which looks like below.

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
------------------------------------
1        1       1       1       0
1        1       1       0       1
2        2       2       2       0
2        2       2       0       2
```

So in effect I would like col4 and col5 to read

```
col4            col5
----------------------
1               1
2               2
```

As I am using SQL Server 2005, I am unable to use `merge`.

Please can someone advise what function would be best to use to get my desired outcome.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(col4), MAX(col5) FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2, col3` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the MERGE statement in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621241/can-i-use-the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2005)