# sql adjacency list children for node

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

given context: [How to copy a node's children in an adjacent list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17879540/139698)

In an adjacency list, how do you pick any node and get all children?

For example, see highlighted nodes below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with CTE([About CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

```
DECLARE @SelectedNode INT = 103;
;WITH nodes AS
( 
    SELECT Node
    , ParentNode
    , GroupID
    , Depth
    FROM TableNodes WHERE Node = @SelectedNode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tn.Node
    , tn.ParentNode
    , tn.GroupID
    , tn.Depth FROM TableNode tn 
    INNER JOIN nodes n ON n.Node = tn.ParentNode
)

SELECT * FROM nodes;
```