# T-SQL: scope_identity() misassigned on xml node parsing

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery, scope-identity

Techies--
I'm shredding through an Xml object without any issues on picking up the correct elements for the correct nodes, however I need to properly update a detail identifier, which is holding on to a single value, when what I really need it to do is refresh that value with the value it just wrote.  I like the efficiency  of the current shredding process--so
I don't want to lose that by coming up with a foolish solution.  Please advise me on the best approach on how to fix this logic.

Here's what's happening:

```
  -- Given:
  -- @OrderXml  is an incoming, populated order containg the header, 
                -- subheaders and    detail records

  -- This logic succeeds
  -- step #1: write the header  row in the header table 
  insert into [order].OrderHeader
  ( col.cone,
    col.ctwo)
  select
   Order.detail.value('(cone/text())[1]','varchar(2)'),
   Order.detail.value('(ctwo/text()) [1]','varchar(2)')
    from @OrderXml.nodes('/Order') as Order(detail)

  select @OrderId = scope_identity()

  -- This logic succeeds
  -- step #2: write the subheader rows in the subheader table

 insert into [order].OrderSubHeader
(col.OrderId,
 col.xone,
 col.xtwo)
select
@OrderId,        -- this works, because no matter how many subheader rows
                -- get generated, the same order id needs to be associated with it.

OrderSub.detail.value('(xone/text())[1]','varchar(2)'),
OrderSub.detail.value('(xtwo/text()) [1]','varchar(2)')
from @OrderXml.nodes('/Order/SubHeader'') as OrderSub(detail)

SELECT @OrderSubId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


-- This logic FAILS
-- step #3: write the detail rows in the detail table

insert into [order].OrderDetail
(col.OrderId,
 col.OrderSubId,  
 col.yone,
 col.ytwo)
  select
   @OrderId,        -- this is correct
   @OrderSubId,     -- this is WRONG when there are multiples
   OrderDet.detail.value('(yone/text())[1]','varchar(2)'),
   OrderDet.detail.value('(ytwo/text()) [1]','varchar(2)')
  from @OrderXml.nodes('/Order/SubHeader/Detail'') as OrderDet(detail)
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you could make use of `merge` and `output` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [OUTPUT Clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You can capture inserted.OrderSubID in addition to any other values you want to insert into the OrderDetail table while you're inserting into OrderSubHeader.  Then use that captured data (in a temp table or table variable) to insert into OrderDetail.