# Insert a record from select statement and bring back identity to same select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an issue with a SQL query

I have a table which has two columns, `employee_name`, `phone_number`. This table has 100 rows.

I want to store `employee_name` in one table and `phone_number` in another table and have a relationship. I will explain the schema

**EmployeeTable**

```
emp_id (identity)
emp_name (text)
ph_id (FK from the phone table)
```

**phone** table

```
ph_id (identity)
phone_number
```

So I tried

```
insert into emp_table (emp_name, ph_id)
select employee_name, (insert into phone_table output inserted.ph_id values (whole.phone)) as phone_id
```

this query is wrong. But this is what I am trying to do.

I want to insert phone number into phone number table and have the identity in the same select statement and insert into the employee table.

Your thoughts?

The final table should be

Whole table (This is what I have now)

```
emp_name   phone_number
----------------------
name1      123
name2      456
name4      789
```

and after query executed

**employee_table**

```
name    ph_id
-------------
name1   1
name2   2
name3   3
```

**phone_table**

```
phone_id   phone_number
-------------------------
1          123
2          456
3          789
```

Comment: a- Did you realy mean that many employees have the same phone number? b- Why did you tag the question as `oracle` and `mysql` ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade if you see the insert query inside select statement, the phone numbers are from the whole table. i.e. each employee have their own phone number but unfortunately both fields are in same table. now i want to split that into two table and have a relatioinship may be Foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that you have your target table structure the way you should but this will do the job with what is in the question.

First insert one row for each *distinct* phone number to `phone_table` and then insert into `employee_table` with a join between `whole_table` and `phone_table` on `phone_number`

```
insert into phone_table(phone_number)  
select distinct phone_number
from whole_table

insert into employee_table(name, ph_id)
select w.emp_name, p.phone_id 
from whole_table as w
  inner join phone_table as p
    on w.phone_number = p.phone_number
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d79a9/4)

**Update:**

You can use `merge ... output` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id) to handle duplicates of phone numbers and names.

Capture the source data with the generated id in a table variable and use the table variable in the insert statement.

```
declare @T table
(
  phone_id int,
  emp_name varchar(10),
  phone_number varchar(10)
);

merge phone_table as p
using whole_table as w 
on 0 = 1
when not matched then
insert (phone_number) values (w.phone_number)
output inserted.phone_id,
       w.emp_name,
       w.phone_number
into @T(phone_id, emp_name, phone_number);

insert into employee_table(name, ph_id)
select t.emp_name, t.phone_id 
from @T as t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/438af/1)

Comment: That was great. One last issue is the user3 and user4 has same phone number and pointing to same ph_id key. There should be two different records even if the number is same. in future the user4 or user3 might update their number and that shouldn't affect other's record. User won't have same number but for some reason, this is my requirement. Could you please help me to complete my task.

Answer (score 0):

Use the @@Identity. Like this:

```
insert into phoneTable(phone_number) values('999888777');

declare @phoneid int

set @phoneid = @@IDENTITY

insert into EmployeeTable(emp_name, ph_id) values('John Supakin', @phoneid)
```

Or, simply this. But be careful with it in long queries.

```
insert into phoneTable(phone_number) values('999888777');

insert into EmployeeTable(emp_name, ph_id) values('John Supakin', @@IDENTITY)
```

Comment: thanks for the query. you did hardcoded the phone number and employee name. the issue is we have to get the values from a select statement.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Thanks, name and phone number are in single table. lets say "whole_table". i just updated my description, please look there for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split into 2 different SQLs. One to insert into EmployeeTable and another for the phonetable.