# INSERT-OUTPUT including column from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure that needs to insert into three different tables, but I need to get the ID generated from the one input and use that to insert into the next table. I'm familiar with the `INSERT-OUTPUT` construct, but I'm not sure how to go about using it in this particular case.

```
DECLARE @guids TABLE ( [GUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER );
DECLARE @contacts TABLE ( [ContactID] INT, [GUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER );
DECLARE @mappings TABLE ( [TargetID] INT, [GUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER );

INSERT @guids ( [GUID] ) ...

INSERT [Contacts] ( [FirstName], [LastName], [ModifiedDate] )
OUTPUT [inserted].[ContactID], g.[GUID]
INTO @contacts
SELECT [First_Name], [Last_Name], GETDATE()
FROM [SourceTable] s
JOIN @guids g ON s.[GUID] = g.[GUID]

INSERT [TargetTable] ( [ContactID], [License], [CreatedDate], [ModifiedDate] )
OUTPUT [inserted].[TargetID], c.[GUID]
INTO @mappings
SELECT c.[ContactID], [License], [CreatedDate], [CreatedDate]
FROM [SourceTable] s
JOIN @contacts c ON s.[GUID] = c.[GUID] 

INSERT [Mappings] ( [TargetID], [SourceGUID] )
SELECT [TargetID], [GUID]
FROM @mappings
```

But I get the following errors:

> The multi-part identifier "g.GUID" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "c.GUID" could not be bound.

I'll get similar errors if I use `s.GUID` instead. Is it possible to do a kind of join in the `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: You're getting the error because you can't use anything other than the INSERTED or DELETED references on inserts (which means you can only use INSERTED, of course). With updates and deletes, you can reference the other tables used in your query. 

The merge option below should work so long as you're using SQL Server 2008 or higher. The only way I've found to do it otherwise is to find an unused column on the table I'm inserting into and put the value (in your case, the guid) into that column, then go back and pull out the column later (and update it back to null so it doesn't stay there).

Comment: try this inserted.GUID

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is the best option, but it seems you can do the trick using `MERGE` :

```
MERGE [Contacts]  trgt
USING 
(  
  SELECT [First_Name], [Last_Name], g.[GUID] as [GUID]
  FROM [SourceTable] s
  JOIN @guids g ON s.[GUID] = g.[GUID]
)src ON (1=0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( [FirstName], [LastName], [ModifiedDate] )
 VALUES (src.[First_Name],src.[Last_Name], GETDATE())
OUTPUT [inserted].[ContactID], src.[GUID]
INTO @contacts
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance. I've never used `MERGE` or even seen it used in the wild. Could you explain this code a bit?

Comment: That's an excellent article.  But, the short answer to your question is that MERGE allows one to combine any combination of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in a single statement (this code forces an INSERT).  MERGE is useful for you here because it allows using columns from different tables in the OUTPUT clause, while INSERT doesn't.

Comment: @GilM and a question about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Or a newer link to [Dr. OUTPUT or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the MERGE](http://dataeducation.com/dr-output-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-merge/) if the other one doesn't work.