# Autoincrement of primary key column with varchar datatype in it

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

in this table `P_Id` is the primary key. We want to generate autoincrement of `P_Id` with default value (PN00) in the start while inserting only LastName and FirstName .eg :-PN001 for first entry ,PN002 for second,PN003 for third and so on .

Comment: Why do you want to do that at all? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? What does `PN` stand for? Adding business meaning to a primary key is a *very* bad idea. If you want to format the key for display, do so in the SELECT statement or with a calculated column

Comment: What is the *actual* requirement?  Are you trying to create a "business ID" or registration number to display to end users? Restricting an ID to 3 or 5 digits is just asking for trouble - imagine having to update all rows once you hit the limit to add one more digit, or if rules change. ERPs solve this by having *two* keys, one actual auto-incremented PK and another one used for display only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only viable solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   P_ID AS 'PN' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `Persons` without specifying values for `ID` or `P_ID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Persons(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `P_Id` will contain values like `PN00001`, `PN00002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Comment: don't forget about gaps in the sequence: it usually happens that people expect a complete sequence using `IDENTITY` but it is not what that's for so there will be gaps.

Comment: @Paolo: yes - gaps happen with `IDENTITY` - but gaps aren't any kind of a problem, really ....

Comment: @Paolo people should *not* attach business meaning to primary keys. They shouldn't even be displayed to users - in fact ERPs contain a second key for display purposes. The OP should explain *why* they key should be displayed in a certain way

Comment: I agree with both but neither you nor me are the op and IMHO is worth mentioning the behaviour of `IDENTITY`, a behaviour that many people seems to forget every day... i have lots of users that writing 'autonumber' expect a complete sequence, that's what triggered a bell in my head ^^

Comment: Thank you Marc_s.Our schema is already created .we cannot alter any column in it.

Comment: @Paolo: if gaps really are a problem (*really?*) then you could use trace flag 272 as a startup parameter - but that'll hurt your performance. Pick one - performance or gaps. You can't have both.

Comment: @gauravbali what happens when you hit customer 999 then? Fixing a bad schema design once you enter production data is *very* hard.

Comment: @panagiotis this is just an example i am discussing .But by default we are using character value in the start .

Comment: @marc_s i **suggested** to mention the behaviour of identity because IMHO many people have wrong expectation about the sequence. that's it. that's my opinion: many people (not me!!!) expect a complete sequence. feel free to ignore my **suggestion**.

Comment: @gauravbali this is a bad idea. You *could* use a SEQUENCE for numbering and an INSTEAD OF trigger to insert formatted keys but that's complicated and still won't save you from modifying a lot of related data when you hit the limit or the rules change. That's why primary keys should *not* have business meaning

Comment: @Panagiotis i agree with you .For the limit part i will have to discuss with my team .But this is for sure that we are using default char value in start.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to address your issue.

1. You could use a **Trigger**.Triggers are activated on some events. You could create a trigger for 'Instead of Insert On Persons' event. When the event is triggered, then generate a new P_Id. Insert this new P_Id alongwith all the values as the new record for your table.

This approach wont have coupling with the table's schema.

Refer this link for more information on Triggers :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx

Refer this link to emulate 'before insert trigger' in SQL Server:
[How to emulate a BEFORE INSERT trigger in T-SQL / SQL Server for super/subtype (Inheritence) entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458006/how-to-emulate-a-before-insert-trigger-in-t-sql-sql-server-for-super-subtype)

2. You could also use a **Procedure** like :

   ```
   create procedure Persons_insert(@lastname varchar(255), @firstname                                    varchar(255))
   as 
   begin
    --write code to generate the ID as you like
    insert into Persons(p_id,lastname,firstname)values(generated_id,lastname,firstname);
   end
   ```

Comment: This is a rather incomplete answer. *How* would the key be generated? *What type* of trigger would be needed - there is no such thing as a 'Before Insert` event

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. Actually I meant to create a trigger which will be executed before the insert statement.