# generate sequence in sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to generate a sequence varchar text type, but I do not want to have to create another column to get the id to format it and insert it I want to generate it in the same column, help

```
create table tbl (
  Id int identity not null,
  CusId as 'CUS' + format(Id, '00000'),
  -- ...
)
```

Comment: Other than cosmetics, there really is no value in zero padding the ID.  I would keep that in the presentation layer.

Comment: SQL Server only has the IDENTITY option for "sequencing" inserted rows, and that "must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable". If you want it displayed in a certain format, you'll either need to do something similar to what you have done, and use a computed column or a Default value, or change the display format on your presentation layer.

Comment: @Larnu I understand what you say but in my opinion what I want to know is if you can, because for example I am generating a code of invoices as you understand the code of the invoice should not be repeated which is an IDENTITY field, for that reason I want to know if it can be done without having to depend on another field

Comment: That was my point @Frankenstainero, no you can't do it with a `varchar`.

Comment: Thanks men, for help but they helped me @Larnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe the only viable solution is using 2 columns as you mentioned, and discussed here:
[Autoincrement of primary key column with varchar datatype in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331265/autoincrement-of-primary-key-column-with-varchar-datatype-in-it)

Have not seen it achieved in a single column on its own.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sequence` object that appeared in SQL Server 2012 + `default value` like this:

```
create sequence dbo.ids as int 
  minvalue 1; 


create table dbo.tbl (
  CusId varchar(100) default 'CUS' + format(NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ids, '00000'));


insert into dbo.tbl (CusId) default values;
insert into dbo.tbl (CusId) default values;
insert into dbo.tbl (CusId) default values;

select *
from dbo.tbl;
-----
--CusId
--CUS00001
--CUS00002
--CUS00003
```