# Trigger to avoid similar names inserted in tables isnt working and not let me insert any row

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this trigger to avoid similar names inserted in a table. But isn't working at all and not let me insert any row (as if the condition is true everytime). I tried with IF EXISTS and happen the same. Even deleting everything in the "Actor" table (leaving with no rows) and when I insert a new one the trigger fires.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[AvoidSimilarName] 
ON [dbo].[Actor] 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Firstname varchar(25)
DECLARE @Lastname varchar(25)
SELECT @Firstname = Firstname, @Lastname = Lastname FROM INSERTED;

SELECT * FROM Actor WHERE @Firstname = Firstname AND @Lastname = Lastname 

IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
END
```

The thing is that when I made a same example of the select that its in the trigger, works fine. Return no rows.

```
DECLARE @Firstname varchar(25)
DECLARE @Lastname varchar(25)
SET @Firstname = 'Johnny'
SET @Lastname = 'Depp'
SELECT * FROM Actor WHERE @Firstname = Firstname AND @Lastname = Lastname
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of select * from, try creating a variable @duplicateNameCount, select the count of matching names into it, and then use the variable instead of @@rowcount for your error eval.

Comment: Also, you are getting the rows that have been inserted. So, it will return the exact same values as the new record every time. Try creating a unique index on the firstname and lastname columns instead of the trigger.

Comment: Not only is a unique constraint the best way to deal with this your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes there will only be a single row in inserted. That is not how triggers work in sql server.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @Firstname = Firstname, @Lastname = Lastname FROM INSERTED;` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get one arbitrary row and ignore all others. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Now is clear to me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not trying to help you with the trigger because i don't think is your best option.

Why not create a unique constraint on those 2 fields?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Actor ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_ACTOR_NAME UNIQUE (firstname,lastname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your trigger always fires because, since you've inserted, you're always going to get a @@rowcount of at least 1.  Try setting it to > 1 and see.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @mxix and @Vinnie that you should probably use a unique constraint for this purpose, another option is to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.  As others have mentioned, your issue right now is that the data has already been inserted so your search is always finding a match, namely the row that was just inserted.  You can use the `INSTEAD OF` trigger to search for the values **about** to be inserted, and decide if you want to insert them or not.

Note that if you go this route, you are responsible for inserting into the table if you deem the data should indeed be inserted. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458006/how-to-emulate-a-before-insert-trigger-in-t-sql-sql-server-for-super-subtype) for some more discussion on emulating a before insert trigger.

Also, as @Sean and @marc_s mentioned, your trigger does not correctly handle multiple rows being inserted in one statement.