# Autoincrement column based on query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, database-trigger

I'm trying a really novice MS Access form (linked to) with a SQL Server in the backend.

So I have a simple table for invoices created with

```
create table Invoice
(
    ID INT not null primary key,
    IssuerID int not null,
    InvoiceID int not null,
    CustomerID int not null
)
```

Maybe I even do not need an ID, since I can uniquely identify entries by pairs (IssuerID, InvoiceID).

All in all, I want to add invoice by `IssuerID` to some `CustomerID` and `InvoiceID` should naturally increment by 1. I can do something like

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(InvoiceID), 0) + 1 AS InvoiceID
FROM Invoice
WHERE IssuerID = @sp;
```

where `@sp` is some value.

In the UI logic, I have a combobox to pick `IssuerID` (ACCESS) and here my problem begin.

I've used a textbox for `InvoiceID`. I want it to update the table by the next ID (i.e. if IssuerID = 5, had 3 issued invoices, next invoice should be numbered 4).
I was not able to make direct SQL work, nor by using VBA in after_update on `IssuerID` combo.

So I've created a view (in SQL Server and linked to it) with all possible IssuerIds and their appropriate nextInvoiceIds.

```
SELECT         
    IssuerID, NextInvoiceID
FROM     
    (SELECT  
         Issuers.ID AS IssuerID, 
         ISNULL(MAX(Invoice.InvoiceID), 0) + 1 AS NextInvoiceID
     FROM    
         Issuers 
     FULL OUTER JOIN 
         Invoice ON Issuers.ID = Invoice.IssuerID
     GROUP BY 
         Issuers.ID) AS UNDATA
```

Next, I was able to pick `nextInvoiceID`, but now I need it to also update the actual column back.

Is it possible from the same textbox?

Should I instead fallback to update this (InvoiceID) with some trigger (or are there other auto-increment options available in SQL Server)?

Comment: Eh... I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Maybe you're just looking for the identity specification (`ID INT not null IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,`) which makes the field auto-increment? Or is there a reason that won't do?

Comment: InvoiceID is unique only up to IssuerID, i.e. IssuerID 5 issued 3 invoices, and IssuerID 6 already 1097, then next InvoiceID for IssuerID 5 should be 4 and not 1098 ! So it is not a PRIMARY KEY alone

Comment: In that case, you could try using an _instead of insert_ trigger in SQL server. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15465988/7296893) gives an overview of modifying the inserted rows before actually inserting them. A complete walkthrough to how to build such a trigger is too broad here imo.

Comment: Why not use IssuerID and InvoiceID as the composite primary key? Doesn't make much sense to introduce another composite primary key.