# Insert Or Update After a Merge

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following MERGE operation on MS SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @data as xml
DECLARE @id as int
DECLARE @version as rowversion
SET @data = ?
SET @id = ?
<# if ( tw.local.enableOptimisticLocking == true ) { #>
SET @version = CAST(? as rowversion)
<# } #>
MERGE [<#=tw.local.dbSchema#>].[<#=tw.local.tableName#>] AS target
USING (Select @id as id, @version version ) as source ON target.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED <# if ( tw.local.enableOptimisticLocking == true ) { #> AND target.version = source.version <# } #> THEN
    UPDATE SET data = @data
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (data) VALUES (@data)
OUTPUT $action as _action<# if ( tw.local.enableOptimisticLocking == true ) { #>, CAST( inserted.version as BigInt) as [version]<# } #>, inserted.id;
```

I wish to have an INSERT / UPDATE statement to another DB and table to update some columns based on the results of the above MERGE.

I am not sure if I can have the other INSERT/UPDATE inside the MERGE or do I need to use Output to get all data I want to INSERT/UPDATE from the MERGE?

I tried the following but it does not work....

```
DECLARE @data as xml
DECLARE @id as int
DECLARE @version as rowversion
SET @data = ?
SET @id = ?
<# if ( tw.local.enableOptimisticLocking == true ) { #>
SET @version = CAST(? as rowversion)
<# } #>
MERGE [<#=tw.local.dbSchema#>].[<#=tw.local.tableName#>] AS target
USING (Select @id as id, @version version ) as source ON target.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED <# if ( tw.local.enableOptimisticLocking == true ) { #> AND target.version = source.version <# } #> THEN
    UPDATE SET data = @data
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (data) VALUES (@data)
OUTPUT $action as _action<# if ( tw.local.enableOptimisticLocking == true ) { #>, CAST( inserted.version as BigInt) as [version]<# } #>, inserted.id, inserted.version, inserted.data;

IF EXISTS (SELECT INSERTED.* FROM INSERTED LEFT JOIN DELETED ON INSERTED.ID = DELETED.id WHERE DELETED.ID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [EMEAworkflowBPM].[cmf].[BusinessContextReporting] (id, version, data, updatedOn, toProcess)
        SELECT i.id, i.version, i.data, GETDATE(), 1
        FROM Inserted i
        LEFT JOIN [EMEAworkflowBPM].[cmf].[BusinessContextReporting] bcr
        ON i.id = bcr.id AND i.version = bcr.version
        WHERE bcr.id IS NULL;
    END
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT INSERTED.* FROM INSERTED INNER JOIN DELETED ON INSERTED.ID = DELETED.ID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [EMEAworkflowBPM].[cmf].[BusinessContextReporting]
        SET version = i.version, data = i.data, updatedOn = GETDATE(), toProcess = 1
            FROM Inserted AS i
            LEFT JOIN [EMEAworkflowBPM].[cmf].[BusinessContextReporting] AS bcr
            ON i.id = bcr.id;
    END
```

Many thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine your OUTPUT with a INTO clause and make the UPDATEs and INSERTs as a new statement following the MERGE.

Take a look at the accepted answer in this question:

[Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)

Comment: Hi Olle the link you gave me seems to use 2 temp tables to store the output results (ie after the merge) into "temp" tables and then from those do his additional select logic. Can I use Output to populate any table I want and add additional columns where I do not have raw data but function calls are made (ie GETDATE()) ?

Comment: Also can you modify the OUTPUT based on whether the MERGE did an INSERT or an UPDATE?

Comment: You may use $action to see from what action the output came from. Like OUTPUT $action, deleted.*, inserted.*

Comment: I think you should be alright inserting your output into a real table.

Comment: I'm not sure about functions calls. You have to try that out! :)

Comment: I have used the $action and combined it with a CASE to know if you should use deleted.id or inserted.id. That's a way of modifying the output, but I don't think its possible to use a whole different output based on the $action.

Comment: That seems to be the correct way to do it. I managed to trace the SQL error after getting some help from the DBA's and I was getting: "The target table 'target' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause."