# Can't use non INSERTED.fields with INSERT...OUTPUT?

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @myTrace TABLE (
srcId int,
destId int);

INSERT INTO Destination ( Refer, OtherData) 
  OUTPUT s.id, INSERTED.id INTO @myTrace  --can't use s.id ??
  SELECT Refer, OtherData
    FROM MySource s
    WHERE somecondition = 1;
```

It seems that SQL Server does not accept fields from MySource if they are not inserted into the destination table. Am I right ? Any workaround ? (I am using 2008 R2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using merge..output to get mapping between source.id and target.id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is unfortunately not possible and there is no fundamental reason it can't be. It is just not implemented.

Use the `MERGE` statement. It allows you to `OUTPUT` everything you like.