# OUTPUT clause to SELECT a column is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use OUTPUT clause to select a column but failed. Here is a quick example,

```
create table A (id int, name varchar(10))
create table B (id int)
insert into A values(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')

declare @Inserted TABLE (ID INT, name varchar(10));

INSERT INTO B
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, a.name INTO @Inserted
select id from a
```

I am getting this error,

```
The multi-part identifier "a.name" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` clause can only refer to the `Inserted` (and possibly `Deleted`) pseudo tables - change your statement to:

```
INSERT INTO B
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, INSERTED.name INTO @Inserted
  SELECT id 
  FROM a
```

Then it should work just fine.

Comment: got this example from, OUTPUT deleted.ScrapReasonID, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx 
       inserted.ScrapReasonID, 
       inserted.WorkOrderID,
       inserted.ProductID,
       p.Name
    INTO @MyTestVar

Comment: See here p.Name is used

Comment: @user960567: true - but that's also an `UPDATE` statement and not an `INSERT`. It seems that with an `UPDATE`, you can refer to tables that are used in the `FROM` clause - while with the `INSERT`, that doesn't seem to work. Don't ask me **why** - just noticed.....

Comment: It seems I can use MERGE with OUTPUT here.

Comment: `B` doesn't have a column called `name`. So `INSERTED.name` doesn't exist. The workaround is to use `MERGE` [as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id)