# Bulk insert related sets of data with unknown auto-incremented IDs

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

We are converting database primary keys from GUIDs to auto-incremented INTs.  We have data that we parse from text files and put into two C# DataTables `Claim` and `ClaimCharge` that we have been using to bulk insert into identically named tables in the database.  In the database, `ClaimCharge.ClaimID` is a foreign key to `Claim.ID` and several claim charges exist for one claim.

With GUIDs we generated the `Claim` and `ClaimCharge` IDs in C#, so bulk inserting was no problem. But with INTs, I don't know what the `Claim.ID` will be, so I can't assign `ClaimCharge.ClaimID`.  I need some ideas on how this could be accomplished with INTs.

For instance, if the `Claim` table could be manually locked against inserts, I could:

1. Bulk insert into alternate tables named `ClaimBulkData` `ClaimChargeBulkData`.  These tables would still use GUIDs for convenience in keeping the relationship maintained between C# and SQL.
2. Manually lock the `Claim` table against inserts (don't know if this is possible) and get the max(ID).
3. Increment all of the data in `ClaimBulkData` using MAX(ID).
4. Associate `ClaimChargeBulkData` to `ClaimBulkData` using the newly updated INT
5. Insert data into real `Claim` table as a set using `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` using some kind of exception to the imaginary lock created in step 2.
6. Release manually created lock against inserts on `Claim` table (again I don't know if this is possible.
7. Insert data into real `ClaimCharge` table.

I want to avoid inserting the data one row at a time in either C# or T-SQL.

Comment: Using this version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5512.0 (X64). Aug 22 2012 19:25:47. Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

Comment: It feels like you are working against SQL Server instead of letting it work for you.  Why not just insert the records as they come instead of doing a bulk insert after you get X amount of records?  It feels like you are going to run into major referential integrity issues.

Comment: Here is another idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365629/using-merge-output-to-get-mapping-between-source-id-and-target-id

Comment: When you parse the text files, how do you distinguish which ClaimCharges will be connected to a Claim? (before generating any connection in C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add the new auto-increment column to the master tables -- you will then have both GUID and autoid column so you can fix up the foreign key relationship (one master table at a time)

i.e.,

Assume you have master1 and detail1 and detail1

```
alter table Master1 add ID int identity(1,1) not null
GO

alter Detail1 add master1ID int null
GO
alter Detail2 add master1ID int null
GO
```

Then update Detail1 and Detail12 based on joining Master1 on the oldguid key to set the corresponding value of Master1ID for each table

You can then add the foreign keys based on Master1ID to Detail and Detail2

At this point you should have a complete set of data based on both sets of keys, and you can test update views, etc. to make sure they work with the new integer ids

Finally, once all is cool, drop to unneeded GUID foreign key and the Guid columns themselves.

You can always run a database pack once you get everything clean and converted if your intent was to reduce overall disk usage via this restructuring. The point is much of the work is fixups for foreign keys in a process like this.

Comment: Very cool, great idea! You blew my mind!  Love the simplicity of it.

Comment: A little more background: inserting into master/detail is an everyday business process so I won't be able to drop the columns.  Space is kind of an issue, but the primary issue for the conversion is lookup/insert performance.  So the plan for now is to leave the old guid columns and rename them to BulkUpdateReferenceId so it's obvious what they're for. After each insert/key fix, I suppose I can set it to null to save space?  But this way there will be no indexes on any guid columns and no lookups using them either, except for the initial FK fix you described.