# How do I insert into Table2 from Table1 and then use the inserted ID to insert into Table3

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I have some tables that store the following data, which is not exactly what I actually have but is simplified so that it's easier to explain..

### Table1

- UserID  (FK)
- TestID (FK)
- StartTime
- EndTime
- QuestionID1
- AnswerToQuestion1
- QuestionID2
- AnswerToQuestion2

Since Table1 is a spreadsheet, I want to import this data into two tables (Table2 and Table3)

### Table2

- UserTestID (PK)
- UserID
- TestID
- StartTime
- EndTime

### Table3

- UserTestID (FK)
- QuestionID (FK)
- AnswerID (FK)

### What I want to do is ...

I want to do the following insertion for each row in Table1.

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(
    UserID
    ,TestID
    ,StartTime
    ,EndTime
)
SELECT UserID
       ,TestID
       ,StartTime
       ,EndTime
FROM Table1


Declare @InsertedUserTestID INT
Set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


-- Do this twice (once for Question1 and the second for Question2)
INSERT INTO Table3
(
    UserTestID
    ,QuestionID
    ,AnswerID
)
SELECT 
    @id
    ,QuestionID1
    ,AnswerToQuestion1
FROM Table1
```

### What I've tried

I read that I can use OUTPUT to use the inserted ID but it doesn't work because it doesn't let me select those columns that are not used to insert into Table2.

```
INSERT INTO Table2
(
    UserID
    ,TestID
    ,StartTime
    ,EndTime
)
OUTPUT Inserted.UserTestID 
INTO Table3(Inserted.UserTestID, QuestionID1, AnswerToQuestion1)
SELECT UserID
       ,TestID
       ,StartTime
       ,EndTime
FROM Table1
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I do the insertion from Table1 to Table2 first, and then use both Table1 and Table2 to insert into Table3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5365629/73226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Martin is right - use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for this.  You could do it all in one statement if you didn't have two row entries to INSERT - as such you could dump to a temp table and do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #answers (UserTestID INT, QuestionID1 INT, AnswerID1 INT, QuestionID2 INT, AnswerID2 INT);

MERGE Table2
USING 
(  
    SELECT UserID
           ,TestID
           ,StartTime
           ,EndTime
           ,QuestionID1
           ,AnswerToQuestion1
           ,QuestionID2
           ,AnswerToQuestion2
    FROM Table1
) src ON (1=0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (UserID, TestID, StartTime, EndTime)
 VALUES (src.UserID, src.TestID, src.StartTime, src.EndTime
OUTPUT Inserted.UserTestID, src.QuestionID1, src.AnswerID1, src.QuestionID2, src.AnswerID2
INTO #answers(UserTestID, QuestionID1, AnswerID1, QuestionID2, AnswerID2);

INSERT INTO Table3
(
    UserTestID
    ,QuestionID
    ,AnswerID
)
SELECT UserTestID
    ,QuestionID1
    ,AnswerID1
FROM #answers
UNION
SELECT UserTestID
    ,QuestionID2
    ,AnswerID2
FROM #answers;
```