# How to INSERT into multiple tables from one SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to insert into multiple tables from one select statement.  Is it possible?

Here is what I am trying to do here:

```
insert into table1 (Name, Address)
insert into table2 (Name, Address)
select Name, Address from MainTable
```

Comment: It is not possible with a single statement.  But why would you want to do this?

Comment: how about a trigger on table1?  add to table2 on insert...

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it **is** possible in a single statement in SQL Server 2008 - the `OUTPUT` clause can do it. (at least for two destinations tables).

Comment: I will go with trigger

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to insert into the second table. If you want to insert into more than two tables, you'd have to use some other method.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @MainTable TABLE (Name nvarchar(50), Address nvarchar(50));
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Name nvarchar(50), Address nvarchar(50));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (Name nvarchar(50), Address nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @MainTable (Name, Address) VALUES
('Name1', 'Address1'),
('Name2', 'Address2'),
('Name3', 'Address3');
```

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO @T1 (Name, Address)
OUTPUT inserted.Name, inserted.Address INTO @T2 (Name, Address)
SELECT Name, Address
FROM @MainTable
;
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM @T1;
SELECT * FROM @T2;


+-------+----------+
| Name  | Address  |
+-------+----------+
| Name1 | Address1 |
| Name2 | Address2 |
| Name3 | Address3 |
+-------+----------+

+-------+----------+
| Name  | Address  |
+-------+----------+
| Name1 | Address1 |
| Name2 | Address2 |
| Name3 | Address3 |
+-------+----------+
```

**Execution plan**

[image: insert with output]

Comment: +1 In general I like this (`OUTPUT` clause is really handy), but am still curious what the actual goal of the O.P. is. Seems like it might be simply to not need to run the query twice, but still.

Comment: @srutzky, yes, it would be good to know the actual problem. In this simple example execution plan is simple and doesn't even have any temporary tables - two INSERTs are chained together. For a complex SELECT query it may be different.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov . . . You are technically correct.  I only use `OUTPUT` with table variables, so I forget it works with any table.  Also, you can only insert values into the second table that are in the first table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff using merge to do the insert would make any columns from the source table available in the output clause http://stackoverflow.com/q/5365629/73226

Answer (score -2):

```
 INSERT INTO school_year_studentid 
             (student_id,syrid) 
      VALUES (
               (
                SELECT student_id 
                  FROM student
                ), (
                     SELECT syr_id 
                       FROM school_year
                   )
                )
```